# Is it possible to have multiple indexes into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Is it possible to have **multiple** indexes **at once** for a single pandas DataFrame?

By index I mean something close to what SQL databases or MongoDB would have to drastically increase the performance of some queries.

Imagine you have a dataframe of orders, and sometimes you would like to index into an order by its ID, and another time by indexing into an order by another key, say warehouse, client ID, time, something like that.

Comment: Yes, you can use MultiIndex and query with IndexSlice. Or you can query like `df.query('ClientID=10')` or boolean indexing: `df[df['ClientID']==10]`

Answer (score -2):

Short Answer : Yes.

Please refer https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])
df.set_index([s, s**2])
      month  year  sale
1 1       1  2012    55
2 4       4  2014    40
3 9       7  2013    84
4 16     10  2014    31
```

Another example for multiple index:

```
dct = {'id' : (0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),
    'Store': ('A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'),
       'code_num':('INC101','INC102','INC103','INC104','INC105','INC106','INC201','INC202','INC203','INC301','INC302','INC303'),
       'days':('4','18','9','15','3','6','10','5','3','1','8','5'),
       'products': ('remote','antenna','remote,antenna','TV','display','TV','display,touchpad','speaker','Cell','display','speaker','antenna')
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
df.set_index(['id','Store','code_num'])
```

df :

[image]

Comment: is it possible to have the second index be a MultiIndex?

Comment: Your question was : Is it possible to have multiple indexes at once for a single pandas DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, but if I want to be able to index with two separate ways as I described in my post, where the first way requires a key with only one item (Order ID), while the second way requires a compound key (Warehouse + client ID + time)), I would need to have two indexes where the first one is a regular Index, while the second one is a MultiIndex. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Updated the example

Comment: Both examples create MultiIndex, but the question was about having independent indices